# How can I know if there are any references to a given instance?

Tags: javascript, weak-references

I am building a queue and if there are no references to this instance of the queue I want to avoid executing any tasks.

I've tried something with `WeakRef` but probably will never work.

```js
const queue = () => {
  const enqueue = () => {
    console.log("enqueue");
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (instanceRef.deref()) {
        console.log("the queue is still referenced so perform task");
      }
    });
  };

  const instance = { enqueue };
  const instanceRef = new WeakRef(instance);
  return instance;
};
b = queue();
b.enqueue();
b = null;
console.log("b is set to null so there are no references to the instance");
```

An alternative would be to check in the tasks if the queue still exists but it's less elegant.

Comment: "*probably will never work*" - why not? Sure that approach would work, you just never wait long enough for the `instance` to actually be garbage-collected.

Comment: Well, never work reliably I guess. How long would you expect to wait? I waited 1 minute was still referenced.

Comment: If it ever decides to be garbage-collected... as it is right now for example, the debugger could probably still use the `instance` ref inside the closure even though it's not used inside the function closure.

Comment: Your code actually works fine if you go the the devtools *Memory* panel and click the *Collect Garbage* button before the timeout occurs. If you want that to happen by itself, you'll need to put some memory pressure on the engine. The garbage collector won't reclaim the memory unless you give it a reason to do - just waiting isn't enough. And even then, your code must never rely on something being garbage-collected. If you want your task execution to be deterministic, you need to do the reference-counting yourself.

Answer (score 1):

One cannot rely on `WeakRef#deref()` to know whether there are still (strong) references to the target object. It merely indicates whether the garbage collector has destroyed the object and reclaimed its memory. This may happen much later, or may never happen at all.

Answer (score -2):

What you want is kinda weird. You want to stop the timeout function magically just by assigning null to a variable that has previously started the timeout function.

What you rather want is to have a method that stops the timeout function. Calling `setTimeout` returns a handler. Store this handler and call the builtin method

`clearTimeout(handler)`

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The timeout is only there to illustrate a point.

Comment: Without a timeout, no function will be executed anyways.